# Mostrar la ultimo dia de cada mes en Fecha AjaxControlToolkit c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Buenas una consulta como hago para que solo este activo el ultimo día de cada mes en fecha en aspx AjaxControlToolkit c# ?

```
<tr>
    <td>Fecha</td>
    <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFecha_FDM" class="form-control" runat="server" Placeholder="Ingrese la Fecha(año,mes,dia)" required></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="Calendar1" PopupButtonID="txtFecha_FDM" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFecha_FDM" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"> </cc1:CalendarExtender>  
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes establecer en `SelectedDate` el último día del mes que se calcularía así y luego bloquear el control para que no se pueda editar ni seleccionar fechas

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
var startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1); // iniciar el primer día de mes
// Establecer esta variable al Calendar
var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1); // este es el último día del mes en curso.
```

Comment: disculpa eso donde lo coloco porque lo pongo y me sale error . yo estoy usando c#  y AjaxControlToolkit c#

Comment: Donde inicializas el Calendar? Se presupone en el Load de la Page. Puedes mostrarnos algo más de código? gracias

Comment: no me logro funcionar me sale todos los calendarios igual